# Jasper Report group subreports using columns

Tags: jasper-reports, grouping, subreport

I have a master report (using iReport 5.0.4) with a subreport that uses grouping by a field called "Group Number" (sorry, but that is the actual column name).

My report works fine when there are more than one group, but it generates each group result scrolling down the page vertically.

I would like to be able to have each group go across vertically, but when I tried using columns, it simply forces each group's data into columns, and not the entire group 1, followed by group 2 in the next column, etc.

There can be up to 8 groups, so I was hoping not to have to create 8 individual sub-subreports with a "print when" expression to show/hide them.

Can anyone tell me if this should be possible?

Thanks,

Mitch

Comment: Can you post the image that illustrates your needs?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think making subreports is the easiest and obvious way. But if you want to make it in other way, I can only suggest to use scriptlet, and form dataset manually (Transpose it).

Another suggestion is when you generating report directly from database (i.e. passing connection into jasper) you can modify query and transpose the data (PIVOT table).

Anyway provide more info about your case. I will try to help you.